# JQuery search and replace in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve in JQuery that once a user click on a link, such as `Feedback.aspx` the `select` attribute from `Default.aspx` `li` will be removed and will be added  to `Feedback.aspx` `li`

```
<ul id="main_menu" class="main_menu ui-sortable">
            <li class="limenu select"><a href="Default.aspx"><span class="ico gray shadow home"></span><b style="">Home</b></a></li>
            <li class="limenu"><a href="OnlineUsers.aspx"><span class="ico gray shadow messenger"></span><b style="">Who is online?</b></a></li>
            <li class="limenu"><a href="Feedback.aspx"><span class="ico gray shadow hand_thumbsup"></span><b style="">Feedback</b></a></li>
            <li class="limenu"><a href="About.aspx"><span class="ico gray shadow info"></span><b style="">About</b> </a></li>
            <li class="limenu"><a href="UserDetails.aspx"><span class="ico gray shadow  user"></span><b style="">User Details</b> </a></li>
            <li class="limenu"><a href="ChangePassword.aspx"><span class="ico gray shadow password"></span><b style="">Change Password</b></a></li>
            <li class="limenu"><a href="Login.aspx"><span class="ico gray shadow power"></span><b style="">Logout</b> </a></li>
        </ul>
```

**EDIT**: My new url is being opened so i need to find `Feedback.aspx` in the new page add `select` to it

Comment: depends on whether the new url gets opened or if the link activates ajax loaded content in same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do :

```
$('li.limenu a').click(function(){
    $('li.limenu').removeClass('select');
    $(this).parent().addClass('select');
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/JxFaM/)

I added `e.preventDefault` in this example to not follow the link, I suppose your example uses a default target to a similar effect.

If you're changing page, the simplest solution is to check at opening what's the page :

```
$(function(){
    var pathtokens = document.location.pathname.split('/');
    var page = pathtokens[pathtokens.length-1];
    $('li.limenu').removeClass('select'); 
    $('li.limenu a').each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('href')==page) $(this).parent().addClass('select');
    });
});
```

Comment: per OP update this will work for ajax content not new page load

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. I saw the update and I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @dystroy.. minor quote issue `'page'` as string not variable

Comment: @user829174 Sorry for the typo. Thanks to charflietfl to point it.